# May I ask during runtime how to check the some kernel command line parameters which not set in the grub but have a default value?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-debugging

I notice there are some kernel command line parameters like below, which from [Manual](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

```
        audit=          [KNL] Enable the audit sub-system
                        Format: { "0" | "1" | "off" | "on" }
                        0 | off - kernel audit is disabled and can not be
                            enabled until the next reboot
                        unset - kernel audit is initialized but disabled and
                            will be fully enabled by the userspace auditd.
                        1 | on - kernel audit is initialized and partially
                            enabled, storing at most audit_backlog_limit
                            messages in RAM until it is fully enabled by the
                            userspace auditd.
                        Default: unset

        audit_backlog_limit= [KNL] Set the audit queue size limit.
                        Format: <int> (must be >=0)
                        Default: 64
```

which has the Default value, so if I am not set it in the grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line, and also not set it during the boot, how do I check that it is indeed using the `Default` value?

The reason why I have such a problem is because there are so many different Linux distribution, I just want to check whether this Linux distribution change the default value. So want to check it in my eyes in the running Linux distribution.

Or is there anything I misunderstand?